# D3.js 4 with AngularJS 1.5 ( Components or Directives ? )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components, d3.js

i want to use D3.js v4 with AngularJS 1.5x

In the past i used **.directives** for the charts, but now i was wondering if it's possible use **.components** instead of directives, and if it's a good practice.

### [Check the sample case on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BHbc5K8MzZk8CIppxbWP)

The problem appears with the `d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')` within components.
The console throw an error: *element is not defined*.

so i tried with something like `d3.select('chart-container').append('svg')`
but then d3 inject all the charts in the first element which own that class ( look for the class in all the document, not only the component ).

---

### **So... can someone help me to do a right d3.select() for a reusable component ?**

without add different ID's for each one ( too much work and too hard for maintain )

Comment: Hey, what is wrong with using directive? You can have controller for directive.

Comment: Just trying to do it in the Angular 2 way, for a easier transition in the future, anyway there should be a way to tell d3 - "Select THIS div only in the component, don't look outside ! "

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass $element to component controller

```
svg     = d3.select($element[0]).append('svg'),
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SMoYLtx4I8RuLf285R6J?p=preview

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
interesting, this select the component itself and append it, but can i point to the div inside of the component template ? 

You know, for a specific location where to append it

Comment: Sure - just always look for it relative to the `$element`, the same way you would in a directive.